# ASP.Net WebApi Help Pages Sample Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.net Help Pages for the WebApi. On some of my response format samples I'm receiving errors that have to do with the formatter. I've looked at various tutorials and they seem to all show how to override the form-url-encoded format. I haven't found anything to override the other formats:

> application/json, text/json, text/html, application/xml, text/xml

In order to set a sample for a specific type I used

```
 config.SetSampleForType("MessageGoesHere", new 
         MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), typeof(TypeGoesHere));
```

and this worked to set the sample for form-urlencoded response formats. I tried replacing the MediaTypeHeader value with application/json or one of the other examples and that had no effect.

**My Question:** How do I set samples for response formats other that form-urlencoded on ASP.net help pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was that I was not using an exact type in the typeof parameter. I was using a generic Collection when I should have been using IQueryable.

```
config.SetSampleForType("MessageGoesHere", new 
     MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"), typeof(ExactTypeGoesHere));
```